# which users are logged in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have two type of users:

1. normal users
2. admins

My requirement is admin can track all user's activity such as who are log in and if he want to log out user profile, then he can log out easily. But I'm not getting how to find user log in activity or when he last seen.

I used this "https://github.com/ctide/devise_lastseenable " for last seen but don't get any conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking is here, https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Answer (score 0):

Or pick from one of these https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/rails_authorization . I would recommended https://github.com/ryanb/cancan